# How can i change background color of unselected tab in tabbar?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

[hello, Iwant to change change background color of unselected tab in tabbar without change indicator color ]

Comment: Please add a minimal code you're using to make tabs

Comment: please add more context to you question. more code examples. Add tags to your question to identify it properly.